# Absolute value inequality example

Tags: absolute-value

Can anyone please help me with this example from Spivak? I am math autodidact.

I have to express this without absolute value:
$$a-|a-|a||$$
The answer is
$$\begin{cases}a&a\ge0\\
3a&a<0\end{cases}$$
All examples went OK, but I dont know this one. I might understand answer by intuition but I can't do it rigorously. Thanks.

Comment: If $a>0$ then $|a|=a$ so your expression is $a-|a-a|=a$.  The case $a<0$ is similar.

Comment: $$a\gt 0\Rightarrow |a|=a\Rightarrow a-|a-a|=a-0=a$$                            $$a\lt 0\Rightarrow |a|=-a\Rightarrow a-|a-(-a)|=a-|2a|=a-(-2a)=3a$$